# getElementsByTagName ("div").length returns zero for any webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to develop a Firefox extension. The following code:

```js
var divList = document.getElementsByTagName("div") ;
Components.utils.reportError("num of divs = " + divList.length) ;
```

Always says:- num of divs = 0.

I don't understand what is the mistake that I am making in this simple piece of code. When I replace `"div"` with `"*"`, I always get a value around 1100 on any webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the difference in the extension context, but it might have to do with namespaces - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName. What is the tag of the first of 1100 elements you get when using "*"?

Comment: what does this mean ? Which element has a nodeName window ?

Comment: From this post: http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/ seems you need `content.document.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Not sure, but my guess `window` is some other XUL element - probably the whole Firefox window.

Comment: That's what it seems to me now. I got the className of document and it is [object XULDocument].

Comment: can you tell me a crisp way of getting at the DOM tree from the extension ?

Comment: What did you get when you tried `content.document.getElementsByTagName("div")`? From what I see, the answer to your last comment is `content.document`.

Answer (score 4):

May be the code is run when the DOM is not ready.

Try to put the JS code inside a `script` tag at the very end of the `body` tag.
I'm not sure why * gets so many items though.

Comment: I run the code by clicking a statusbarpanel button after the pages have completely loaded.

Comment: did you try `document.body.getElementsByTagName` ?

Comment: are you sure that there is a property called body ? Firefox tells me that document.body is undefined.

Comment: strange, in Firefox and all the other browsers here it does give the reference of the body tag.