# getElementsByTagName().length returns zero

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to do a simple thing such as:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
console.log(elements);
console.log(elements.length);
```

The console.log(elements) shows the NodeList containing 28 input elements, but the elements.length is always 0.

I've also seen this [getElementsByTagName("div").length returns zero for any webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179209/getelementsbytagnamediv-length-returns-zero-for-any-webpage) however I didn't understand what exactly is the reason for it happening and how to fix it. I've also noticed that this happens on both Firefox, IE, Chrome.

Anyone could help me out?

Comment: Can't quite remember for sure, but try doing elements.length() - length may be a function, can't remembe.r

Comment: Are you sure you are calling your code when the document/DOM is loaded? It might be, that while calling getElementsByTagName, no input elements exist, but since NodeLists are dynamic, when the document loads, elements will contain all 28 inputs.

Comment: It would seem that DOM isn't loaded. Copy and paste this in the URL of your page to see what it is after DOM loads. javascript:var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("input");alert("elements has "+elements.length+" children");

Comment: You are right, it's because the DOM isn't loaded. Thanks both Rafael, and adorablepuppy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NodeList` is a live collection and non-deferred scripts execute immediately (see script defer).

Try this and you will get an idea of what happens:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style></style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    alert(elements.length); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    alert(elements.length); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's saying `console.log(elements)` and `console.log(elements.length)` are reporting inconsistently.  If you put that here, I'm betting it'll show 1 element, `1`, and 2 elements, `2`.

Comment: I got it. I will mark this as the correct answer since you got into the trouble of giving it with an example, although both comments above are also correct :) Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: To solve the issue, one option is to move the script to after the body loads

Comment: Can you go into more detail. I am trying to figure out the same issue. I ran the code and see 0 on first and 1 on second call of length. What about when I have the var elements in the body of the code? Where would I put the alert to give length 1? For instance I have a script that calls a .js file inside my body which sets up a few <path > elements. I call length after the body, but still see 0 length. Something like <body>"script file here</body> document.getElementByTagName().length

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the asynchronous behaviour of JS. You're trying to display the element's value before it is being rendered.
In order to avoid it, you could add the "async" attribute to your  tag, as in the following example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myTag.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your script should have the attribute "deter" to detect the tags

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After you have gained 50 rep points you will be able to post comments.