# Got multiple elements with getElementsByName, Changing their names gets weird results

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyname

I have a form with multiple input(text) elements with the same name

```
<input name="val[]" type="text" />
<input name="val[]" type="text" />
<input name="val[]" type="text" />
```

Now, say I want to change their names to "val2[]".

This is what I originally wrote:

```
var vals=document.getElementsByName("val[]");
var valct=vals.length;
    for( var i=0; i<valct; i++ )
        vals[i].name="val2[]";
```

However this seems to be getting me an error.
From Chrome's developer tool it says "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

After thinking for some time, I figured that the element might be deleted after renaming.
Therefore, I changed the last line of the code to:

```
vals[ 0 ].name="val2[]";
```

And this works !

But then, I was thinking if I could code it this way:

```
while( vals=document.getElementsByName("val[]") )
    vals[0].name="val2[]";
```

This gives me the same error I got above "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"
I am puzzled. I also tested it with Firefox and the results were the same. (cannot test on IE because I use HTML5 native DnD on the page)

It seems to me that what getElementsByName returns is a queue while changing names acts as removing items from one.
Is this true? or what is the correct explanation for this ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844732/getelementsbytagname-length-returns-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you changing attribute, which you are using as selector for `document.getElementsByName` and it return `NodeList` object to you, not an `Array`. `NodeList` it is a live collection of DOM elements ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)). So after you name attribute modification it will contain less than 3 elements ([demostration](http://jsfiddle.net/XhRr5/1/)).

Try to modify you code like an example below, and this will solve you problem, because you will get an static `Array` instead of `NodeList` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2nTc/)).

```
var vals = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName("val[]"));
var valct = vals.length;
for( var i=0; i<valct; ++i ) {
    vals[i].name="val2[]";
}
```