# How exactly does getElementsByClassName work in Chrome?, specifically w.r.t. NodeLists & DOMs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getelementsbyclassname

All of the following results were obtained using Google Chrome v36 & its console.

While debugging a Wordpress plugin, I discovered that running this little Javascript snippet

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("switch-tmce"))
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("switch-tmce").length)
```

would log the following (expanded after the page finished loading):

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]
    0: a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    1: a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    length: 2
    ninja_forms_field_10-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    ninja_forms_field_15-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
0
```

If I adjusted the snippet to wait for the DOM to finish loading like so:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("switch-tmce"))
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("switch-tmce").length)
}, false);
```

it would then log the following (expanded after the page finished loading):

```
[a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce, a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce, ninja_forms_field_10-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce, ninja_forms_field_15-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce, item: function, namedItem: function]
    0: a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    1: a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    length: 2
    ninja_forms_field_10-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_10-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    ninja_forms_field_15-tmce: a#ninja_forms_field_15-tmce.hide-if-no-js.wp-switch-editor.switch-tmce
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
2
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is just what exactly is happening here - in particular, why the `length` property only returns "correctly", so to speak, *after* the DOM loads. I've found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844732/getelementsbytagname-length-returns-zero):

> It might be, that while calling getElementsByTagName, no input elements exist, but since NodeLists are dynamic, when the document loads, elements will contain all 28 inputs.

but I'm reading that as saying that getElementsByTagName parses the NodeList until it can parse the DOM, and can only return the `length` property when parsing the DOM, which doesn't seem right to me, since it still has finite countable elements.

Moreover, there's also the matter of `[item:function, namedItem:function]` changing to `[a.someClass.someOtherClass, a.someclass.someOtherClass]`, which the above doesn't explain.

Hence my question: What exactly is happening under the hood with `getElementsByClassName` that the `length` property is not set (does not exist?) until after the DOM loads, despite that the prototype remains the same? How is this related to/why does the output change from `[item:function, namedItem:function]` to `[a.someClass.someOtherClass, a.someclass.someOtherClass]`?

Comment: Hmm, some deep thinking here. Want to work at ECMAScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` - that is, a *live* reference for your query.

What's happening is that you're expanding the *live* reference in the console after the DOM is ready, but logging it *before* the DOM is ready. Because it is a *live* reference, by expanding when the DOM is ready, when the `HTMLCollection` references the object in the memory, it sees that the DOM is ready and pulls from the finished DOM.

If, however, you expanded the reference while having paused the execution of the Javascript (this can be done with something like `debugger`), this is what you would get:

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]
    length: 0
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
0
```

because the DOM would not yet be ready then.

That's why the first logged reference showed up as `[item: function, namedItem: function]`, because when you logged it, the DOM wasn't ready. Once the DOM was ready, it was logged as `[a.someClass.someOtherClass, a.someClass.someOtherClass]`.

The length output, though, is just a number, not an object reference, and logs as is, which is why it prints 0 before the DOM is ready and 2 after it is - because that's *exactly* what's happening, since there are no DOM elements before the DOM is ready.

Comment: You lost me at "But the length output is just a number, not a object reference." If there are no DOM elements before the DOM finishes loading, what is `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("switch-tmce"))` returning _before_ DOM finishes loading? What "class" are you referring to when you say "there was no DOM elements with that class."?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Well, lets try again :P 
The query result is a object. Thus, when you do a ``console.log`` it prints a reference to the object. When you click to see the content of a object printed by ``console.log`` it gets the data from the current state of the object, and not from the state of the moment you ``console.log`` it. BUT, the number is not a object, thus it is printed the value itself, and not the reference to the number. Got it ?

Comment: Try writting ``debugger;`` after you ``console.log`` outside the ``DOMContentReady`` event. And then, open object printed in the console, it will be empty. Because the ``debugger;`` stop the javascript execution. So the current state of the printed object will be empty.

Comment: YES, this does indeed make sense. Now I see what you mean! So what exactly is it that `getElementsByClassName` is returning before the DOM finishes loading then? It still returns `[item: function, namedItem: function]`, unless that's just a placeholder?

Comment: It's a ``HTMLCollection`` object.

Comment: Expanding in the console after pausing with the debugger tells me that it's a `NodeList`, though: `[item: function] length: 0 __proto__: NodeList`. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no DOMElements at this moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59236/discussion-between-samuel-lijin-and-joao-mosmann).

Comment: Whoops, realized that I was invoking debugger on the wrong output - it actually spits out `[item: function, namedItem: function] length: 0 __proto__: HTMLCollection`. Confusion solved!

Answer (score 1):

Nodelist is a superset to HTMLcollection. Specifically Nodelist is the constructor which makes HTMLcollection.

`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
console.log(list)`

Now you will see :

```
__proto__ : NodeList();
console.log(NodeList) //-> function NodeList()
```

So a HTMLcollection is just a nodeList that contains elements and not text. (Nodelist's can contain text)
to form a nodelist you must use the methods:
Node.childNodes 
Element.classList

and probably some recursion to build it.

Comment: in this example. list is  a htmlcollection.